# How to pass data to childview in laravel 5

Tags: php, view, laravel-5

Is there a clean way to pass data to a child view that has been included through blade's @include? Since I know that Im going to be using the same code throughout my website I have decided that a particular variable name must be available for the child view to implement its display.

At first I used something like the following:

```
foreach($user->$posts as $requiredNameForChildView){
 @include('mychildView') //child view uses $requiredNameForChildView
}
```

But then things got more challenging with other views since I did not always need to loop through an array of objects as before, not allowing me to assign an alias using the 'as' in the foreach. In these cases Im opening a php environment and assigning $requiredNameForChildView before entering the child view but this does not seem to be inline with Laravel's clean code practices.

What are the best practices behind doing something of this sort?

Answer (score 0):

It should work without any additional code as variables are available in all views. Did you try just use it?

For checks of any kind you can just use `@if ... @endif` construction or `ternary` operator.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#control-structures

Comment: Thanks for replying. I dont really need to check something before calling the child view, my issue is in variable assignment. I call the @include statement more than once at different parts of the page. I have to pass in an array of images,  and produce an image slider using the child view. But that just means that I have to reassign the variable, depending on what part of the page im on, before calling the child view. I cant find a clean way to do that.

Comment: Why do you need to reassign variable? You recieve all variables from your controller and can use all of them in all your views... It's not clear for me, can you post some simple example code?